# Is there an item that can temporarily relieve madness?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sanity

I have an NPC that I'm going to have go completely bonkers. I want to get the players to go a-questing for an item or plant or something of the like so they can get plot information out of him. Is there anything that can temporarily relieve madness like this?

I would prefer not to homebrew or make something up considering it's only a 3 or 4 session campaign to test out a new, more erratic player before adding them into an ongoing campaign.

Comment: Does it need to be a temporary fix?

Comment: It doesn't need to be, but it would be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

One such option is the [Elixir of Repression](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/elixir-of-repression) from Champions of Corruption:

> [...] An imbiber who is afflicted with any form of madness receives a +4 insight bonus on any saving throws made to resist the effects of that madness during the elixir's duration. A dose of elixir of repression lasts for 12 hours.